# "type <class 'builtin_function_or_method'> not mapped to pf type" error using redshift_connector and insert_data_bulk()

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I keep getting a "type <class 'builtin_function_or_method'> not mapped to pf type" error when trying to bulk insert a .csv file into an existing Redshift table using the insert_data_bulk() function within the redshift_connector library for python. I am using pandas to create the csv from a dataframe.

After a few failed attempts with my real data, I decided to create a mock table in Redshift with just one empty string column and tried to insert a mock .csv with just one row with a string (no headers). Still after that tiny test I continued getting the "type <class 'builtin_function_or_method'> not mapped to pf type" error.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.